# Hide Repetitive data in sql

Tags: sql, toad

I would like to ask for some reference i could use to for my studies for SQL
I am currently doing a report in which i would hide the repetitive data and keep the unique data.

My example is that i have three columns in table sales:

- Fruit
- Purchaser
- Quantity of Purchased Fruit

---My Current progress------

```
FRUIT   PURCHASER QUANTITY
APPLE   BAN       11
APPLE   BEN       2
MANGO   BON       9
MANGO   BUN       10
MANGO   BAAN      10
ORANGE  BAIN      5
ORANGE  BAON      3
```

----My Goal output--------

```
FRUIT   PURCHASER QUANTITY
APPLE   BAN       11
        BEN       2
MANGO   BON       9
        BUN       10
        BAAN      10
ORANGE  BAIN      5
        BAON      3
```

Thank you

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: While you can do this in SQL (usually with `LAG`), one should rather do such layout-only things in the presentation layer, which is your app or Website.

Comment: That you use the tool Toad is irrelevant here. What matters is the database system (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, ...), because it's the DBMS that has or lacks features that may be needed.

Answer (score 3):

What order do you have?
You can use window function.
`ROW_NUMBER()` is a window function that assigns a sequential integer to each row within the partition of a result set.

In your case, you need to have partition by fruit and decide what row's order you need.

If you have order by quantity by descending:

```
select 
    case when num=1 then FRUIT else '' end as FRUIT, PURCHASER, QUANTITY
    from
    (
       select *,row_number()over(partition by FRUIT order by QUANTITY desc)num 
       from Table
    )x
    Order by FRUIT, num
```

If you need to have order by PURCHASER, then try this query:

```
select 
    case when num=1 then FRUIT else '' end as FRUIT, PURCHASER, QUANTITY
    from
    (
       select *,row_number()over(partition by FRUIT order by PURCHASER)num 
       from Table
    )X
  Order by FRUIT, num
```

Comment: Sou, do you try query?)

Answer (score 1):

First, it is important to know what type of operations are suitable for databases and which are not.  This is not really suitable, although it can be done.

Second, the reason it is not suitable is because each row should stand on its own.  Results sets are not ordered *unless* there is an explicit `order by`.  Sometimes they might look like hey are coming in a particular order, but only `order by` guarantees it.

You can do what you want in SQL, but you have to be careful with how the query is constructed.  The basic logic is a `case` expression:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by fruit order by purchaser desc) = 1
             then fruit
        end) as fruit, purchaser, quantity
from t
order by fruit, purchaser;
```

Even this version has a potential bug:  If a fruit has two rows with the maximum quantity, then then two `order by`s could return the tied values in a different order -- meaning that the fruit name appears on the second row.

That suggests a subquery instead so `row_number()` is only calculated once and it can be used directly in the `order by`:

```
select (case when seqnum = 1
             then fruit
        end) as fruit, purchaser, quantity
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by fruit order by purchaser) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by fruit, seqnum;
```

Comment: I surmise the desired order is Fruit, Purchaser, not Fruit, Quantity. And these columns are probably unique in the data set. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Too new to comment -- sorry.

This can be done with SQL, however, developing re-usable data sets is usually to your advantage.  The type of presentation you're looking for would more typically be done in the presentation layer (not the data / sql layer).

Which reporting tool are you using?

Comment: While I agree that this should better be a comment (and such comment even already exists), this is still a helpful answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Just use analytical lag funtion:

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9449d/5)

```
select fruit_new as fruit, purchaser, quantity from (
select a.*, case when lag(fruit) over(order by fruit)  = fruit then null else fruit end as fruit_new
from table1 a order by fruit) ;
```

Comment: Why the outer query? It is not needed. The subquery alone suffices. And if you wrap the real query in a superfluous outer query, you should at least move the `ORDER BY`clause out of the subquery (where it can be ignored, because subqueries return an unordered set by definition) to the main query in order to guarantee an ordered result.